# order week number and resp. data in mysql starting with 51 and ending with week 12

Tags: mysql

I have got this query which shows snowdepth by weeknumber. There is no other date(ish) registration in the table other than wk, 1,2 3, etc.

```
SELECT 
  res_id,
  wk,
  ROUND(templo, 0) AS templo,
  ROUND(temphi, 0) AS temphi,
  ROUND(snow_valley, 0) AS snow_valley,
  ROUND(snow_mountain, 0) AS snow_mountain 
FROM
  sv_cond_vw_wk 
GROUP BY res_id,
  wk 
HAVING (res_id = 6) 
  AND (wk = 51 
    OR wk = 52 
    OR wk = 52 
    OR wk < 13)
```

It outpuths week 51 and 52 after week 12 but I would like to have it before week number 1:
51,52,1,2,3,4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FIELD(wk,52,51) DESC` in `ORDER BY` clause so that wk => 51 will appear first then wk => 52 and then rest ones

```
SELECT 
  res_id,
  wk,
  ROUND(templo, 0) AS templo,
  ROUND(temphi, 0) AS temphi,
  ROUND(snow_valley, 0) AS snow_valley,
  ROUND(snow_mountain, 0) AS snow_mountain 
FROM
  sv_cond_vw_wk 
GROUP BY res_id,
  wk 
HAVING (res_id = 6) 
  AND (wk = 51 
    OR wk = 52  
    OR wk < 13)
ORDER BY FIELD(wk,52,51) DESC , wk
```